# np.all() does not get executed

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a script:

```
import numpy as np
a=[0,0,0]
if np.all(a==0):
    print('All are zeros!')
```

but nothing gets printed out. Shouldn't `np.all(a==0)` evaluate to be True since all elements in `a[]` are `0`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` must be a numpy array in order to get `array([True, True, True])` as the result of `a == 0`.

Change `a=[0,0,0]` to `a = np.array([0,0,0])` and then try again.

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid explicitly converting list `a` to a `numpy.ndarray`, you can call `numpy`'s comparison operators directly:

```
np.all(np.equals(a, 0))
```

However, if your data are already a Python list, simply use Python's `all()` to get the same result at a fraction of the time it takes `numpy` to compute `all()`:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: a = [random.random() for _ in range(1000000)]

In [4]: %timeit all(x == 0 for x in a)
615 ns ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit np.all(np.equal(a, 0))
24.2 ms ± 2.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```